# Merge Sort on an array of floating point numbers of fixed size 25 (C programming language)

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point, numbers, mergesort

My code is as follows:

```
void mergeSort(float a[], int first, int last) {
     //Function performs a mergeSort on an array for indices first to last
     int mid;
     //if more than 1 element in subarray
     if(first < last){
              mid =(first + last) / 2;
              //mergeSort left half of subarray
              mergeSort(a, first, mid);
              //mergeSort right half of subarray
              mergeSort(a, mid+1, last);
              //merge the 2 subarrays
              merge(a, first, mid, last);
              }
}



void merge(float a[], int first, int mid, int last){
     //Function to merge sorted subarrays a[first -> mid] and 
     //a[(mid+1)-> last] into a sorted subarray a[first->last]

     int ndx1; 
     int ndx2;
     int last1;
     int last2;
     int i;
     ndx1 = first;
     last1 = mid;
     ndx2 = mid + 1;
     last2 = last;
     i = 0;

     //Allocate temporary array with same size as a[first, last]
     float temp[SIZE];

     while((ndx1 <= last1) && (ndx2 <= last2)){
                 if(a[ndx1] < a[ndx2]) {
                            temp[i] = a[ndx1];
                            ndx1 = ndx1 + 1;
                            i++;
                            }
                 else{
                      temp[i] = a[ndx2];
                      ndx2 = ndx2 + 1;
                      i++;
                      }
     }

     while(ndx1 <= last1){
                temp[i] = a[ndx1];
                ndx1 = ndx1 + 1;
                i++;
                }

     while(ndx2 <= last2){
                temp[i] = a[ndx2];
                ndx2 = ndx2+1;
                i++;
                }

     int j;           
     i = 0;
     for(j = 0; (last-first) ;j++){
           a[j] = temp[i];
           i++;
           }

}
```

It runs a few times, but then it locks up and says it has stopped working.  There are no errors, and I wrote this right from an algorithm sheet.  I don't understand why it is locking up.  Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: For fixed-size sorts a sorting network should be optimal. 25 is bordering too big but you could split it in half and then do a non-recursive merge.

Comment: congrats on reaching 15 rep! you can up-vote answers now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you (try to) copy back the values from `temp` int the array,

```
 for(j = 0; (last-first) ;j++){
       a[j] = temp[i];
       i++;
       }
```

1. For `first != last`, you have an infinite loop, that causes the reads and writes to go outside the array bounds, and sooner or later leads to a segmentation fault or access violation. You meant to write `j <= (last - first)` as the loop condition. But
2. You are copying back to the wrong part of the array, you always start at `a[0]`, but it should start at `a[first]`, the loop should be

   ```
   for(j = first; j <= last; ++j) {
       a[j] = temp[i++];
   }
   ```

Comment: It works now. Thank you very much.  Quick question:  I did mean to write j <= (last - first) as the loop condition, and I obviously messed that up, but could you maybe explain why that wouldn't work?  If I increment J each time through with j++ wouldn't it start at the front of the array (Temp) to copy back?  (Sorry for confusion, I've only been using C for 6 days as of today.)

Comment: Because `for(j = 0; j <= (last-first); ++j)` would copy each part of the array to the beginning of the array. It would eliminate some array entries and duplicate others, and not sort the array. The issue is where in `a` you write the entries back.

Comment: What exactly is the difference b/w ++j  and j++?  I used j++, and my program still works?

Comment: Ah, that. That's in this case just a matter of custom or preference. There is a difference if the value is used (`++j` returns the incremented value, `j++` the non-incremented), but as a loop-counter increment, both are translated to the same code by any good compiler. I'm just used to always writing the prefix increment operator there. (Note that I used `i++` in `a[j] = temp[i++]` because there the difference matters, I want the old value.)

Comment: Ok. I appreciate your willingness to explain all of that.